# Jackrabbit MSSQL database repository

Tags: sql-server, jackrabbit, wildfly-9

Any specific reason why abruptly connection to MSSQL server is lost. I am running web application on the same machine so network connectivity issues are out of question. My application uses Jackrabbit configured to store content with MSSQL. Application is running on Wildfly v9 with JAVA_HOME set to jdk1.8 and I have verified that wildfly is picking it up as well. Also, sqljdbc4-3.0.jar is available to wildfly modules with proper driver configuration in standalone. I am baffled as to why jdk7 adapter would be called to manage connection. However, interesting observation is that this does not occur with Wildfly 10.

standalone.xml

```
<driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
       <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
       <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

exception:

```
ERROR 21-07 16:41:13,636 (DbUtility.java:logException:92)    failed to close ResultSet
ERROR 21-07 16:41:13,637 (DbUtility.java:logException:94)           Reason: IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk7.WrappedConnectionJDK7@386eff84
ERROR 21-07 16:41:13,639 (DbUtility.java:logException:95)       State/Code: null/0
```

Comment: I am only familiar with MS SQL, and I can assure you that an established connection will get a session which will only go to sleep status if there is no activity, and will awake if there is any incoming query. All this is transparent to the client (webapp) and that will always see a valid connection. If i were you, i would start to sniff around in the webapp configuration. Connection closing is usually controlled at web server level, like in IIS. If you don't find anything you may start to use Fiddler (free web debugging app) to catch what's going on on app level

Comment: Same application runs fine with Wildfly 10 so there has to be some server level configuration I do not know otherwise it could be a bug with Wildfly 9.